# Some questions about Google Data Studio and Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

How to get the `languageCode` in the method `getData()`? Or just outside the `getConfig()` method? I read that `languageCode` is passed in the `request` parameter of the `getData()` method. I have other properties of the config. But `languageCode` not. This is the output of the `request`parameter:

```
{dateRange={endDate=2018-12-17, startDate=2018-11-20}, fields=[{name=Field_1}, {name=Field2}]}
```

This is my getConfig method:

```
function getConfig(params) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var config = cc.getConfig();

  var lang = params['languageCode'];

  config
  .newInfo()
  .setId('id_1')
  .setText(i18n('SomeText'))

  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);

  return config.build();
}
```

And one more question. When I throw an exception in a message, along with the text of the exception, a string is also displayed on which I threw an exception. Is there any way to hide this information? And just display the text of the thrown exception? Without the string on which the exception was thrown?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> And one more question. When I throw an exception in a message, along with the text of the exception, a string is also displayed on which I threw an exception. Is there any way to hide this information? And just display the text of the thrown exception? Without the string on which the exception was thrown?

The debug information is only shown when `isAdminUser()` returns `True`. To omit this information, set this to return false.